# implementing location based services

Tags: android

i am trying to implement this [tutorial](http://blogoscoped.com/archive/2008-12-15-n14.html) but i am getting errors in these line

```
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.MyLocationOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
```

in WhereAreMyFriendsMap.java

Is there anything else like jar i need to add 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set your Project Build Target to the Google APIs version of the API level you're targeting.  You most likely have it set to Android API.

Comment: I have checked from API level 3 to level 10 but it doesn't work (:

Comment: But did you download the Google API's by Google Inc packages in Eclipse?  They don't come by default.  You should see an Android and a Google API's line for each API level, and you need to select the Google one...it contains the Maps libraries.

Comment: please can u guide me about any tutorial that how can i download Google API's for Google Inc packages in Eclipse?

Comment: In Eclipse, Window > Android SDK and AVD Manager.  Select Available packages on the left.  I believe it's under Third party Add-ons, and then you select Google Inc.  I forget exactly and mine looks different because I already have it installed, but just look around and you'll find it.

Answer (score 1):

From the same tutorial, do you have everything they mentioned here?

```
Getting started is pretty well-worn ground. Pull down the latest Android SDK and JDK (5 or newer). Download and install Eclipse for Java developers (3.2 or newer) and the ADT Eclipse plugin and you're set. There's more detail at StackOverflow, on the Android code site, and the Android support forums.
```

Comment: I have checked from API level 3 to level 10 but it doesn't work (: